# Image dynamically added to all Salesforce apex emails

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

Any time I send an email from Apex using the messaging class, Salesforce is automatically adding an image to the bottom of the email. The image appears as a box with a red x in outlook. This looks bad and as though the system is in error. How do I go about removed the dynamically added image?

Below is an the html of the image that is added inline to the email:

http://exampleorg--DEV.cs63.my.sales=
force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid=MASKED&esid-MASKED">=

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So this issue appears only in the outlook desktop client for emails that were sent via the Apex messaging class. The image that you are seeing is automatically added by Salesforce. The image is used for some of the emailed based tracking features that make Salesforce powerful.

Outlook detects this as an image with an invalid URL. When outlook see's an invalid image it displays a box with a red x to indicate where the image should have loaded. Which is why you are seeing the red x box in the email. If you turn of the automatic downloading feature within outlook you can disable all red boxes, but then outlook won't automatically download images, ever, paired with the fact that you have no control over users outlook deployment. Which leads me to the following resolution.

The image (and therefore the red box) can be removed if you disable email tracking under the sales app activity settings. Note that Salesforce will no longer track email metrics such as emails opened. You will no longer be able to run accurate html email tracking reports if you disable this feature.

Follow the paths below and uncheck the setting in your production environment to resolve this issue.

Classic
Setup | Build | Customize | Activities | Activity Settings | Enable Email Tracking (checkbox)

Lightning
Setup | Feature Settings | Sales | Activity Settings | Enable Email Tracking (checkbox)​